# Parameter IN SQL in R

Tags: r

could you please help me with changing parameters in sql query in R studio

it could be something like this

target <- "POJ"

FPV_MREL_POJ <- dbGetQuery(con, "select LINE_REF_COLL from DM_IFRS.FPV_MREL_",target[1]")

but it doesnot work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to use `paste0` function in your code.

```
target <- "POJ"

sql_query <- paste0("select LINE_REF_COLL from DM_IFRS.FPV_MREL_", target[1])

FPV_MREL_POJ <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)
```

EDIT: following code does both what OP asks for, and tries to prevent code injection as pointed out by Sirius in the comments:

```
library(glue)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")

target <- "POJ"

tbl_name <- paste0("FPV_MREL_", target[1])

sql_query <- glue_sql("select LINE_REF_COLL from DM_IFRS.{tbl_name}", .con =  con)

FPV_MREL_POJ <- dbGetQuery(con, sql_query)
```

Comment: You should _always_ escape values that go into SQL queries.

Comment: Sure. SQL injection is a well established attack vector. We know nothing of OP's context. The day that his `target` variable has the value `'POJ; delete from DM_IFRS.FPV_MREL_POJ; --'` , he will likely struggle to find out what really happened. And just deleting rows is probably the best thing that could happen. Here's a brief introduction: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp , it was also popularized by xkcd back in the days: https://xkcd.com/327/ .

Comment: OP asked how to fix a not-working, parameterised query, not how to prevent code injection.

Comment: And why would he. He is asking how to contstruct an SQL query from parameters. That _always_ happens through sanitation.
If your friend was strugling with the gas pump, you would also tell him to put out his cigarette, even if technically that's not why he asked you over.